# Trouble with Codeigniter and JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreign-key-relationship

All I am trying to do is query a database table for a list of counties in my state. I want to pull 5 cities that correspond to those counties and list them on the page. I am using a JOIN in order to do this because that is what my searching lead me to believe that I need.

So far I am passing all of the information from my Model to my Controller, and then displaying it in my View with no issues. The problem is that the cities list seems to be limiting its self to only 1 city per county. Do you see a problem with my query? I have tried (seemingly) everything, but because I am so new I am sure that there is something silly that I am missing.

```
<? 
class Index_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function countiesWithCities() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("cities");
        $this->db->join("counties", "cities.county_id = counties.county_id");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

This is the result of that query:

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (5) { 
["city_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
["county_id"]=> string(1) "5" 
["city_name"]=> string(8) "Munising" 
["county_name"]=> string(5) "Alger" 
["number_of_cities"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#18 (5) { 
["city_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["county_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["city_name"]=> string(7) "Redford" 
["county_name"]=> string(5) "Wayne" 
["number_of_cities"]=> string(1) "2" 
} 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#19 (5) { 
["city_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["county_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["city_name"]=> string(7) "Livonia" 
["county_name"]=> string(5) "Wayne" 
["number_of_cities"]=> string(1) "2" 
} 
[3]=> object(stdClass)#20 (5) { 
["city_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
["county_id"]=> string(1) "4" 
["city_name"]=> string(6) "Monroe" 
["county_name"]=> string(6) "Monroe" 
["number_of_cities"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 
[4]=> object(stdClass)#21 (5) { 
["city_id"]=> string(1) "4" 
["county_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["city_name"]=> string(16) "Farmington Hills" 
["county_name"]=> string(7) "Oakland" 
["number_of_cities"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 
}
```

It seems fine but for example, array[2] should have more cities listed under it, other than "Livonia." I can't seem to figure out how to complete this? Anyone have any advice or help?

Comment: Try `$this->db->join("counties", "counties.county_id = cities.county_id");`

Comment: @Mudshark that doesn't seem to change anything at all

Comment: Edit your question to be very clear about exactly what you want your view output to look like. Your comments below are still not clear. (And should be in your question.) "Listing the counties and cities" is *vague*. Loop" is what code does, not what output looks like. Do not say what this query "should" return. It *does* return what it should return; you should correct your expectations. (You likely want either an array of (county_id,county_name,array of (city_id,city_name)) or to order the query above.) *Exactly describe your desired view output.*

Comment: @philipxy, you are exactly right and I apologize. I actually got it working. I am too new to provide my answer but I will post exactly what I did to get it working. I will make sure to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I ended up getting rid of the JOIN because the array it was giving me was a 1:1 ratio for county to city. I needed it combined. So I queries the counties table and looped through that. As I looped through that I did loop through the cities data and checked to see if the county_id in the cities table matched the id in the counties table.

Model:

```
public function countiesWithCities() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("counties");
    $this->db->where('number_of_cities >', 0);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function getCities() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("cities");
    $this->db->order_by("county_id", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
    $data['counties'] = $this->index_model->countiesWithCities();
    $data['cities'] = $this->index_model->getCities();


    //The page "home" does exist, so load the views in the following order
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/indexmain', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

View:

```
<?php 
foreach ($counties as $county)  {

    echo "<strong>".$county->county_name."</strong> <br>";

    foreach($cities as $city) {
        if($city->county_id == $county->id) {
            echo $city->city_name."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

From here I can style it and organize it on the page. Thank you so much for the help everybody. I hope this can help someone else with my problem. Also if anybody has a more efficient way of doing this I'd be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You are printing results from both cities and country table. Please see the select table line.
Since country table have only one row with county_id, it will print only one row.
**controller function**

```
public function counties()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('counties');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
public function Cities() {
    $this->db->select("cities.*");
    $this->db->from("cities");
    $this->db->join("counties", "cities.county_id = counties.county_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And Now in **view page** use double for each like below.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($rs_countrytable as $rs_countrytable_value)  
    {

  echo $rs_countrytable_value->country_name;
?><br/>
<?php
        foreach ($rs_Cities as $rs_Cities_value)
        { 
        if(($rs_countrytable_value->county_id)==$rs_Cities_value->county_id)    
          {
          echo $rs_Cities_value->city_name;?><br/><?php
          }
        }
     }?>
```

Comment: While this does work to list all of the cities, how do I go about listings the counties and cities? Do I use two different queries to do that. I assumed with join() I'd be able to do one query to get all results and then loop through it? Edit: Also, thank you for your time thus far.

Comment: First let me know that Are all the cities listed with the above query? And are you like to print the corresponding country also?

Comment: Yes, all cities are listed. The array contains the city_id, county_id that it belongs to, and city_name. what I would ultimately do is loop through the results and display something like: countyOne - city, city, city; countyTwo - city,city,city; countyThree - city, city, city in my View.

Comment: The issue is that I am doing my database query in my model and not my controller so the above code is missing controller code. This does work however so it is leading me in the right direction!

Comment: If you want to add the function in model paste that in your model and go to controller to call model function. You may know how to call the model function. $data["function_result"]=$this->model->function();